# Unable to ssh into windows vm from cloud-build-local

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I'm setting up a CICD pipeline, part of which involves ssh-ing into a windows VM.
To run these CICD tests locally, we're using [`cloud-build-local`](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-debug-locally#install_the_local_builder) and deploying (an extensive version of) the following file:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        mkdir -p /root/.ssh/
        cp vm_config /root/.ssh/config
        cp vm_id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
        cp vm_id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        apt-get install sshpass
        echo 'START SSHING'
        echo $(sshpass -p 'VMPASS' ssh anmol@VM_ADDRESS -R 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 "dir")
        echo 'END SSHING'
    id: Start Windows VM
```

However, the ssh step here does not run/output anything (not sure which one). The output just looks like:

```
START SSHING

END SSHING
```

I've confirmed some basics like:

- the VM exists
- the ssh command runs and outputs from my local terminal.
- I've tried disabling the pseudoterminal with -T as well.

From what I understand, `cloud-build-local` should be using my service account so there shouldn't be any issues with any permissions.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting any error? if so, Can you share error log?

Comment: Nope, no error!

Comment: Can you go through this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/enable-debugging-mode-in-ssh/) once. which might help you